# Buttons From Previous Pages Are Still Clickable

Tags: python, pygame, click, mouse, tic-tac-toe

I'm programming a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game using pygame module in python so as to gain the basics of this language. While coding, I run into something weird: There are four states in the game:
   1) Start screen : There are two buttons here : 'player vs player' and 'player vs cpu'
   2) 'Player vs cpu' screen : There are four buttons here : easy, medium, hard, expert
   3) Game screen : Game board will be here
   4) Final screen : There is one button here for returning back to main menu

The problem is when I'm in start screen and click on the 'player vs cpu' button, it changes state to 'Player vs cpu' screen. However, since 'expert' button from this state and 'player vs cpu' button from previous state are overlapped as location, it keeps changing state to Game Screen state without clicking on 'expert' button.
  I couldn't figure it out. Appreciated helps in advance.

Here is some of my code:

```
def start_screen_state(mouse, click):
    start_screen = StartScreen(gameDisplay, screenX, screenY)  # .ven bilmem ne gibi bir dosyada degisiklik yapiyormusum. ondan hata aldim
    global state # her fonk.da global olmasini istiyorsak bildiriyoruz. ilgili fonk.da artik bu degiken globaldir.
    PVPxCoord = screenX - int(screenX * 0.8)
    PVPyCoord = screenY - int(screenY * 0.4)
    PVCxCoord = screenX - int(screenX * 0.3)
    PVCyCoord = screenY - int(screenY * 0.4)
    # for PVP button
    if (PVPxCoord < mouse[0] < PVPxCoord + start_screen.get_PVP_Button().getWidth()) and (PVPyCoord < mouse[1] < PVPyCoord + start_screen.get_PVP_Button().getHeight()): #PVP butonu icin
        start_screen.get_PVP_Button().modifyButton("light_pvp_button.png", "resized_light_pvp_button.png")
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = GAME_SCREEN
    # for PVC button
    if (PVCxCoord < mouse[0] < PVCxCoord + start_screen.get_PVC_Button().getWidth()) and (PVCyCoord < mouse[1] < PVCyCoord + start_screen.get_PVC_Button().getHeight()): #PVC butonu icin
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = PVC_SCREEN



def game_screen_state(mouse, click):
    game_screen = GameScreen(gameDisplay, screenX, screenY)
    global state


def pvc_screen_state(mouse, click):
    pvc_screen = PVCScreen(gameDisplay, screenX, screenY)
    global state
    # for easy button
    easy_x_Coord = pvc_screen.get_easy_button().getX()
    easy_y_Coord = pvc_screen.get_easy_button().getY()
    if (easy_x_Coord < mouse[0] < easy_x_Coord + pvc_screen.get_easy_button().getWidth()) and (easy_y_Coord < mouse[1] < easy_y_Coord + pvc_screen.get_easy_button().getHeight()):
        pvc_screen.get_easy_button().modifyButton("light_easy_button.png", "resized_light_easy_button.png")
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = FINAL_SCREEN # GAME_SCREEN diye update edilecek. FINAL_SCREEN test icin bu sekle getirildi
    # for medium button
    medium_x_Coord = pvc_screen.get_medium_button().getX()
    medium_y_Coord = pvc_screen.get_medium_button().getY()
    if (medium_x_Coord < mouse[0] < medium_x_Coord + pvc_screen.get_medium_button().getWidth()) and (medium_y_Coord < mouse[1] < medium_y_Coord + pvc_screen.get_medium_button().getHeight()):
        pvc_screen.get_medium_button().modifyButton("light_medium_button.png", "resized_light_medium_button.png")
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = GAME_SCREEN
    # for hard button
    hard_x_Coord = pvc_screen.get_hard_button().getX()
    hard_y_Coord = pvc_screen.get_hard_button().getY()
    if (hard_x_Coord < mouse[0] < hard_x_Coord + pvc_screen.get_hard_button().getWidth()) and (hard_y_Coord < mouse[1] < hard_y_Coord + pvc_screen.get_hard_button().getHeight()):
        pvc_screen.get_hard_button().modifyButton("light_hard_button.png", "resized_light_hard_button.png")
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = GAME_SCREEN
    # for extreme button
    extreme_x_Coord = pvc_screen.get_extreme_button().getX()
    extreme_y_Coord = pvc_screen.get_extreme_button().getY()
    if (extreme_x_Coord < mouse[0] < extreme_x_Coord + pvc_screen.get_extreme_button().getWidth()) and (extreme_y_Coord < mouse[1] < extreme_y_Coord + pvc_screen.get_extreme_button().getHeight()):
        pvc_screen.get_extreme_button().modifyButton("light_extreme_button.png", "resized_light_extreme_button.png")
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = GAME_SCREEN




def final_screen_state(mouse, click):
    gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
    final_screen = FinalScreen(gameDisplay, screenX, screenY)
    global state
    menu_x_Coord = final_screen.get_main_menu_button().getX()
    menu_y_Coord = final_screen.get_main_menu_button().getY()
    if (menu_x_Coord < mouse[0] < menu_x_Coord + final_screen.get_main_menu_button().getWidth()) and (menu_y_Coord < mouse[1] < menu_y_Coord + final_screen.get_main_menu_button().getHeight()):
        # final_screen.get_menu_button().modifyButton("light_menu_button.png", "resized_light_menu_button.png")
        # LIGHT FOTO GELINCE ACILACAK
        if click[0] == 1:
            state = START_SCREEN

def current_state(mouse, click):
    if state == START_SCREEN:
        start_screen_state(mouse, click)
    elif state == PVC_SCREEN:
        pvc_screen_state(mouse, click)
    elif state == FINAL_SCREEN:
        final_screen_state(mouse, click)
    elif state == GAME_SCREEN:
        game_screen_state(mouse, click)


while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    current_state(mouse, click)
    click = None
    mouse = (0, 0)
    pygame.display.update()  # flip'i de dene
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please read the [minimal, complete and verifiable example page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A runnable example would be really helpful in order to analyze and debug the program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you are not erasing the screen before blitting the new one. I would recomend do a 'gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))' before the 'pygame.display.update()' line (I don't see where you blit the other surfaces, though) to "clean" it before redrawing.

Comment: Thx for ur reply! But when I do that, whole screen came black. In current_state function, whenever any of inside function of current_state function is invoked, i.e. Pvc_screen_state function, its __init__ is invoked firstly. Inside __init__ I invoke gamedisplay.fill((0,0,0)). This is what ı've done for all states. I invoke fill function at the beginning of their __init__

Comment: You should clean the screen before redrawing. That is, in the update method, because the init method is only called once. The code would be "fill, draw, update screen")